# how can i bubble sort array that storing a class field?

Tags: c#, bubble-sort

```
    void Bubblesort(City []cities, int num)
    {
        
        for(int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < num - 1 - i; j++)
            {
                if (cities[j].CityTemperature < cities[j].CityTemperature + 1)
                {
                    var tempvariable = cities[j];
                    cities[j] = cities[j + 1];
                    cities[j + 1] = tempvariable;
                }
            }
        }   
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cities[i].ToString()); 
            
        }
    }   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("welcome to enter the name of the city and its temperature between -60 and 60 Celsius \n you will have to enter 4 elements of each :-) \n\n\n\n");
        City[] cities = new City[4];
        Program myProgram = new Program();
        var num = cities.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < cities.Length; i++)
        {
            cities[i] = new City();
            Console.Write("Name of City ?: ");
            cities[i].CityName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("what Temp ?: ");
            cities[i].CityTemperature = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
        }

        myProgram.Bubblesort(cities, num);

        Console.WriteLine("press a button of choice and hit enter to close the program, \n Byebye :-)");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

/// My City class

private string name;
private int temperature;

```
    public string CityName
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public int CityTemperature
    {
        get { return temperature; }
        set { temperature = value; }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        
        return "City: " + CityName + " City temperature: " + CityTemperature;
    }
```

So basically user input City name and City
temperature that are stored into fields of the class,
i want to bubblesort the array by the temperature so it will
make an output sorted from coldest to warmest.
can you see where to begin with ? i been trying to
figure out if im passing wrong arguments when calling the function
and been trying to change withing the loops and experimenting.
im thinking maybe that i dont compare the temperature values
and it does something else. however the sorting is never occuring.
appreciate the time you take to look at this.*

Comment: Is there a reason why you're implementing a sorting algorithm yourself rather than using the built-in ones?

Comment: What do you expect of us? That we debug your code? That's not what we do here. You should learn how to debug your code yourself. Learn how to use a debugger to step though your code. Write unit tests. And if you have a very specific problem or error, ask a focused question.

Comment: `cities[j].CityTemperature < cities[j].CityTemperature + 1` <- think about this. explain to yourself what this is doing.

Comment: @JHBonarius I guess (I'm saying this for OP's benefit) that OP meant `cities[j].CityTemperature < cities[j + 1].CityTemperature`?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar yea, of course we can just give people the anwer. But do they learn from that? So IMHO it's not for the OP's benefit.

Comment: @JHBonarius Unless your intent is that they learn to use the debugger (as Damien's is) then I think this appears to be a simple typo that they didn't spot. If it isn't, then it should be easy to understand why it's wrong, so easy to learn from. I agree that we shouldn't give people everything on a silver plate as that takes away the opportunity for learning, but I don't think this is such a case.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I've been teaching professionally and trained to do so. Typos like this indicate an underlying problem. It's better to learn people how to solve their own problems than to give them an answer.